# Commutator of QFT Operators $[\hat{a}_p, \hat{a}^\dagger_k]$ and 4-Momentum Integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation, operators

I just recently started looking into CAS (i.e. i have very little experience in Mathematica), specifically for doing basic calculations in Quantum Field Theory.

For that i would like to define $\hat{a}_p$ and $\hat{a}_q^\dagger$ with
$$[\hat{a}_p,\hat{a}_q] = [\hat{a}_q^\dagger, \hat{a}_q^\dagger] = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad
[\hat{a}_p, \hat{a}_q^\dagger] = (2\pi)^3\,2E_p\,\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})$$
as well as typical momentum integrals
$$\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E_p}$$
I've already looked at [*FeynCalc*](https://feyncalc.github.io/) for the 4-vectors, but the packet is more specific to calculations of Feynman graphs rather than these more elementary operator manipulations.

Whats the best way to approach this?

Thanks.

---

**Details on the Problem**

As a simple example consider a classical field $\phi(x)$ ($\phi^3-$theory) with
$$(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu + m^2)\phi(x) = -\frac{g}{2}\phi(x)^2$$
For $g=0$ the exact solution can be written as
$$\phi^{(0)}(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\left(a(p)e^{-ipx}+a^*(p)e^{ipx}\right)\Big|_{p_0=E_p}$$
The typical approach in quantization is to build such a field not from simple functions $a(p)$, but the creation and annihilation operators given above. Then one can treat the interaction term perturbatively in the quantized free theory.

Instead, i wanted to solve the equation perturbatively already at the classical level, which (beyond first order) is already quite tedious and only
then replace $a(p)$ by $\hat{a}_p$. With this i then want to check the commutator relation
$$[\phi(x), \pi(y)] = [\phi^{(0)}_x, \pi^{(0)}_y] + [\phi^{(1)}_x, \pi^{(0)}_y] + [\phi^{(0)}_x, \pi^{(1)}_y] + \text{higher orders}$$
too see if it still satisfies the free field commutation relation (i.e. if the order (1) and higher contributions cancel)

The higher order terms can be computed using the Feynman propagator
$$\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{-ipx}}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$
hence also (possibly) the need for the 4-momentum integrals.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Depending on the problem you want to solve, this might be a very good way to learn how to use Mathematica.  But, for help, you should provide an explicit calculation with the steps and result so that we know what you'd like Mathematica to do.

Comment: Generally, several attempts have been performed to realize commutators as you have written them, one place you might start to look at is [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html).

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have updated the question to give a specific problem. Please let me know if I should add additional clarification.